# Android resource linking failed. See the console for details

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Can someone please help making sense of this? My project in Unity is no longer building after I changed the "company name" field in Project Settings, the android dependency resolver ran and undoing name change doesn't fix the problem. I have tried many solutions but changing the Gradle version hasn't helped nor did changing the target Android API.

```
    Note: C:\Users\...\Desktop\games\newVer\...\Temp\gradleOut\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\unity3d\player\UnityPlayerActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':launcher:processReleaseResources'.
    > Android resource linking failed
    C:\Users\...\Desktop\games\newVer\...\Temp\gradleOut\launcher\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\release\AndroidManifest.xml:41: AAPT: error: unexpected element <queries> found in <manifest>.


    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

    BUILD FAILED in 1m 25s
    Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

    UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

    CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
    C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.17f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.17f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-5.1.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

    stderr[
    Note: C:\Users\...\Desktop\games\newVer\...\Temp\gradleOut\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\unity3d\player\UnityPlayerActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':launcher:processReleaseResources'.
    > Android resource linking failed
    C:\Users\...\Desktop\games\newVer\...\Temp\gradleOut\launcher\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\release\AndroidManifest.xml:41: AAPT: error: unexpected element <queries> found in <manifest>.


    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

    BUILD FAILED in 1m 25s
    Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
    ]
    stdout[
    Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 2 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

    > Configure project :launcher
    Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.17f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\build-tools\28.0.3\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
    Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.17f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
    Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.17f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
    Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.17f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\build-tools\28.0.3\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
    Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.17f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
    Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.17f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only

    > Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :launcher:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:checkReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:checkReleaseManifest
    > Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseManifest
    > Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:processReleaseManifest
    > Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
    > Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
    > Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
    > Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
    > Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseResValues
    > Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseResources
    > Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig
    > Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
    > Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
    > Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseSources
    > Task :unityLibrary:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:packageReleaseResources
    > Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseRFile
    > Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseBuildConfig
    > Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseSources
    > Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:javaPreCompileRelease
    > Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseAssets
    > Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild
    > Task :launcher:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
    > Task :launcher:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
    > Task :launcher:checkReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :launcher:generateReleaseBuildConfig
    > Task :launcher:generateReleaseSources
    > Task :launcher:mainApkListPersistenceRelease
    > Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseRFile
    > Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :launcher:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
    > Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
    > Task :unityLibrary:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForRelease UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:transformNativeLibsWithIntermediateJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:bundleLibCompileRelease
    > Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:mergeReleaseShaders
    > Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseShaders
    > Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseAssets
    > Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:packageReleaseAssets
    > Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:bundleLibRuntimeRelease
    > Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
    > Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:bundleLibResRelease
    > Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
    > Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
    > Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForRelease
    > Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:transformNativeLibsWithIntermediateJniLibsForRelease
    > Task :launcher:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests
    > Task :launcher:processReleaseManifest

    > Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac

    > Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibCompileRelease
    > Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibRuntimeRelease
    > Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibResRelease
    > Task :launcher:processReleaseResources FAILED

    Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
    Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
    See https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
    50 actionable tasks: 32 executed, 18 up-to-date
    ]
    exit code: 1
    UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <d76da2c9a45b4b02b93f56ae560b1d44>:0)
    UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <d76da2c9a45b4b02b93f56ae560b1d44>:0)
    UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <d76da2c9a45b4b02b93f56ae560b1d44>:0)
    UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <d76da2c9a45b4b02b93f56ae560b1d44>:0)
    UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <d76da2c9a45b4b02b93f56ae560b1d44>:0)
    Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
    UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <d76da2c9a45b4b02b93f56ae560b1d44>:0)
    UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <d76da2c9a45b4b02b93f56ae560b1d44>:0)
    UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <d76da2c9a45b4b02b93f56ae560b1d44>:0)
    Rethrow as BuildFailedException: Exception of type 'UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException' was thrown.
    UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuild (System.String title, System.String message, System.Exception ex) (at <d76da2c9a45b4b02b93f56ae560b1d44>:0)
    UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <d76da2c9a45b4b02b93f56ae560b1d44>:0)
    UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <d76da2c9a45b4b02b93f56ae560b1d44>:0)
    UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <d76da2c9a45b4b02b93f56ae560b1d44>:0)
    UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <2f1c602eae0d45c293fff3e3aef759fa>:0)
    UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Copy `<UnityEditor>/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools/GradleTemplates/baseProjectTemplate.gradle` to `<Project>/Assets/Plugins/Android`
2. Edit it, change the version of the gradle plugin to 3.4.3

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.3'
    }
}
```